# Decomposition of a monomial ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals

I have to find a primary decomposition of the following ideal and I proceeded in this way:

$$(x^2z,x^2y^3,xt^2)=(x)\cap(t^2,x^2z,x^2y^3)=(x)\cap(t^2,x^2)\cap(t^2,z,z^2y^3)=(x)\cap(t^2,x^2)\cap(t^2,z,y^3)\cap(t^2,z,x^2)$$

Now I have to show that $(t^2,z,x^2)$ is redundant and I can prove that fact saying that it contains $(t^2,x^2)$.

How can I show (in a simple way) that other ideals are irredundant?

Comment: Can you find a monomial which is in the intersection of the first two ideals  and which is not in the intersection of the three?

Comment: In general if I decompose a monomial ideal in that way I obtain something like $I=\bigcap_i^n Q_i$. This is not always a minimal decomposition, so I need to find which $Q_i$ are redundant. In the case discussed above it is easy to show that $(t^2,z,x^2)$ contains $(t^2,x^2)$ and I can throw it away. But this is a particular case and in general I need to show that each $Q_i$ doesn't contain the intersection of the other $Q_j$ for $j\ne i$ and I think that this process could be more expansive if I have to face a lot of $Q_i$. So my real question is: is there an easier way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

`You can use evaluation.`
Lets prove $x\notin (t^2,x^2):$ otherwise $x=t^2f+x^2g.$ Evaluation of $t$, $x$  at $0$, $x$ leads to a contradiction.
 Using appropriate evaluation you can say $z\notin (t^2,x^2), $ and so on.